# Problem With error Handling in nodejs with fastify

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, error-handling, fastify

I came across a problem that I can't solve with simple nodejs error handling. Because the error is only reported in the terminal but does not come back with the request as a response.
What ends up happening is that in my routes, if I experience a failure with zod and it gives an error, what I would expect is for it to return the error in the request, but that is not what is happening.

```
import { CreateUserService } from "./CreateUserService";
import z, { ZodError } from "zod";

import { FastifyReply, FastifyRequest } from "fastify";

class CreateUserController {
    constructor(private createUser: CreateUserService){}
    async handle(request: FastifyRequest, reply : FastifyReply){
       
        const schema = z.object({
            name: z.string(),
            address: z.string(),
            cellNumber: z.string().min(8)
        })
       
      
        const {name, address, cellNumber} =schema.parse(request.body)
      
       
       
        const user = await this.createUser.execute({name,address,cellNumber});
        return reply.send(user)
    }
}

export {CreateUserController};
```

this is my createUserController, in it the error when I send the json that is expected by zod is missing some data the error is reported in the server terminal, even though I create a middleware for error handling it is not directed there.
However if i implement the validation in the router is work:

```
import { FastifyInstance } from "fastify";
import { createUserFactory } from "../modules/createUser/CreateUSerFactory";
import {z} from 'zod'

export  async function router (app:FastifyInstance){
    app.get("/", (request,reply)=>{
        return reply.send("OK")`your text`
    })

    app.post('/user',(request,reply)=>{
        const schema = z.object({
            name: z.string(),
            address: z.string(),
            cellNumber: z.string().min(8)
        })
        const {name, address, cellNumber} =schema.parse(request.body)
    
  //  createUserFactory().handle(request,reply);
})
}
```

I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong as the error is not returned by the request

Comment: Could you add the stack trace too?